# Understand output of Integration

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, piecewise

Could someone help me understand the output of the following Integration in Mathematica?

Specifically,

(a) what is the meaning of "True"?

(b) Why is the answer in two parts which seem to overlap i.e. x >= 1, and x > 0, but one part is still subtracted from the other?

(c) If the evaluated integral is plotted, it's showing up as a smooth curve, but the result itself doesn't get any more compact with FullSimplify?

```
$Assumptions = Element[x, Reals] && Element[x1, Reals] &&  t > 0 && k > 0; 
G1=Tanh[Sqrt[(x - x1)^2]/Sqrt[2]]
G01 = FullSimplify[Integrate[G1*1, {x1, 0, 1}]]
```

Output with Mma 12.0 on Windows 10

```
Piecewise[{{-1 + x + Sqrt[2]*Log[4/(1 + E^(Sqrt[2]*(-1 + x)))], 
 x >= 1}}, 1 - x + Sqrt[2]*
 Log[1 + E^(Sqrt[2]*(-1 + x))]] - Piecewise[{{x + Sqrt[2]*Log[4/(1 + E^(Sqrt[2]*x))], x > 0}}, -x + Sqrt[2]*Log[1 + E^(Sqrt[2]*x)]]
```

Comment: (a) The documentation for `Piecewise` shows it has a slightly different definition than the standard (US) math def.: "The $\text{cond}_{\,i}$ are evaluated in turn, until one of them is found to yield `True`." (c) Plot the derivative to better see the piecewise nature of the result.

Comment: Hi Michael E2, do you imply plotting the derivative of each of the evaluated terms/pieces? Thanks

Comment: `Plot[
 Evaluate@D[G01, x],
 {x, -1, 2}]`

Answer (score 2):

1. `True` means 'everywhere else' or 'otherwise' in the piecewise expressions.
2. *Mathematica* determined it was simplest to break it into two parts. That probably comes from an identity  involving `Tanh` used in the substitution.
3. You can use `PiecewiseExpand` on the integration result to get this simpler result:
   $$
   \begin{cases}
    \sqrt{2} \log \left(\frac{4}{e^{\sqrt{2} (x-1)}+1}\right)-\sqrt{2} \log \left(\frac{4}{e^{\sqrt{2} x}+1}\right)-1 & x\geq 1 \\
    -2 x+\sqrt{2} \log \left(e^{\sqrt{2} (x-1)}+1\right)-\sqrt{2} \log \left(\frac{4}{e^{\sqrt{2} x}+1}\right)+1 & 0<x<1 \\
    \sqrt{2} \log \left(e^{\sqrt{2} (x-1)}+1\right)-\sqrt{2} \log \left(e^{\sqrt{2} x}+1\right)+1 & \text{True}
   \end{cases}
   $$
   A `FullSimplify` will combine the sums of logarithms into logarithms of products:
   $$
   \begin{cases}
    1-\sqrt{2} \log \left(\frac{e^{\sqrt{2}}-1}{e^{\sqrt{2} x}+1}+1\right) & x\geq 1 \\
    -2 x+\sqrt{2} \log \left(\frac{1}{4} \left(e^{\sqrt{2} (x-1)}+1\right) \left(e^{\sqrt{2} x}+1\right)\right)+1 & 0<x<1 \\
    \sqrt{2} \log \left(\frac{e^{\sqrt{2} (x-1)}+1}{e^{\sqrt{2} x}+1}\right)+1 & \text{True}
   \end{cases}
   $$